# How to check last time an Azure SQL Database went on Auto-Pause and for how long?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, serverless, azure-cli

I'm testing Azure SQL Database with the Serverless feature.

I would like to understand if the SQL Database went into Auto-Pause mode yesterday and for how long.

I asked to ChatGPT to give me a hint about what code I can use and it suggested PowerShell:

```
az sql db show -g $resourceGroupName -s $serverName -n $databaseName --query "automaticPauseTime"
```

But it's returning the error:

```
(ResourceGroupNotFound) Resource group 'MyResourceGroup' could not be found.
Code: ResourceGroupNotFound
Message: Resource group 'MyResourceGroup' could not be found.
```

Even if I put the right Resource Group name.

So I tried with T-SQL:

```
USE master;

DECLARE @databaseName NVARCHAR(128) = 'YourDatabaseName'; -- Replace with your database name
DECLARE @lastConnectionTime DATETIME;

-- Get the last connection time from the sys.dm_exec_sessions DMV
SELECT @lastConnectionTime = MAX(login_time)
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
WHERE database_id = DB_ID(@databaseName);

IF @lastConnectionTime IS NULL
BEGIN
    PRINT 'The database has never been connected since the last restart or creation.';
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'The database last had a connection at: ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @lastConnectionTime);
END
```

Which returns `The database has never been connected since the last restart or creation.` which is a lie because I'm connected to it right now.

So how can I check the last time an Azure SQL Database went on Auto-Pause and for how long?

Comment: *"which is a lie because I'm connected to it right now."* Incorrect; you are connected to `master` and checking if there are any connections to `YourDatabaseName`. If you *were* connected to `YourDatabaseName` then your statement `USE master;` would generate the error *"USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to connect to a different database."*

Comment: Thank you, you are right, but I connected to it multiple times in the last 2 hours during the investigation. So it's still telling BS

Comment: Run `SELECT DB_ID(N'YourDatabaseName');`; notice the result is `NULL`. Therefore your query will always return no results as `database_id = NULL` can never be true. `DB_ID` only works for the database you are connected to in Azure SQL Database. So `DB_ID(N'master'`) will return a value when connected to `master`, but otherwise will always return `NULL`.

Comment: Now it makes sense, thank you @ThomA. I see this query will not help me find how many hours this database spent in Auto-Pause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same question, but then I noticed Activity Log. It's possible to drill into the change details for the DB.

in the Azure Portal, go to the DB > Activity Log > choose an event (pausing & resuming are events, I found out). look for Properties.Status, properties.pausedDate, properties.ResumedDAte or something similar to get the last time paused or resumed.

These details are change activities logged to Azure itself in the DB config. if you don't have permissions to see what history and values that have changed, you may not have the ability to see that information.

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot of where you picked properties.pausedDate etc

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I found was to use the Metrics from the Azure Portal: **Successful Connections Count**

[image]

Otherwise if you have the audit enabled at server level you can target the Strage Account and query the logs this way:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.fn_get_audit_file('https://MyDomain.blob.core.windows.net/sqldbauditlogs/weu-cust-mssql-srvr/MyDatabase/SqlDbAuditing_ServerAudit/2023-07-30/', DEFAULT, DEFAULT)
```